# How can I get the numbers for the correlation matrix from Pandas Profiling

Tags: pandas-profiling

I really like the heatmap, but what I need are the numbers behind the heatmap (AKA correlation matrix).
[image: Heatmap example]

Is there an easy way to extract the numbers?

Answer (score 3):

It was a bit hard to track down but starting from the documentation; specifically
from the [report structure](https://pandas-profiling.github.io/pandas-profiling/docs/master/report/index.html) then digging into the following function [get_correlation_items(summary)](https://pandas-profiling.github.io/pandas-profiling/docs/master/report/structure/correlations.html) and then going into the source and looking at the usage of it we get to this call that essentially [loops over each of the correlation types](https://github.com/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling/blob/develop/src/pandas_profiling/report/structure/correlations.py#L67) in the summary, to obtain the summary object we can find the following, if we lookup the caller we find that it is [get_report_structure(summary)](https://github.com/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling/blob/3d0d0e4bb85a32cd7b7cd63e7ad083cb9a65970c/src/pandas_profiling/report/structure/report.py#L309) and if we try to find how to get the `summary` arg we find that it is simply the `description_set` property as shown [here](https://github.com/pandas-profiling/pandas-profiling/blob/3d0d0e4bb85a32cd7b7cd63e7ad083cb9a65970c/src/pandas_profiling/profile_report.py#L173).

Given the above, we can now do the following using version 2.9.0:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport

df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.rand(100, 5),
    columns=["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]
)

profile = ProfileReport(df, title="StackOverflow", explorative=True)

correlations = profile.description_set["correlations"]
print(correlations.keys())
```

```
dict_keys(['pearson', 'spearman', 'kendall', 'phi_k'])
```

To see a specific correlation do:

```py
correlations["phi_k"]["e"]
```

```
a    0.000000
b    0.112446
c    0.289983
d    0.000000
e    1.000000
Name: e, dtype: float64
```

- [Sample Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1_UW4UtulLlWUZ-oAxBzN-xpsfbtkxm9_?usp=sharing)

Comment: The sample notebook link seems to be broken